# replace a jsp Include page from another jsp

Tags: java

i have a index.jsp which is responsible for all the css. there is this line of code

```
<jsp:include page="Includes.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

includes.jsp is a page which stores all the css layout. is there anyway for me to replace the include page from another jsp page?

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear ?

Comment: so its basically like i have an new created jsp page "themes.jsp". i would like to replace the include page in index.jsp to another jsp from themes.jsp

Comment: YES! use costume tags

Comment: hi. would u give me some examples on how u would use consume tags in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.is there anyway for me to replace the include page from another jsp page?

No.

But you can do one thing here , you can dynamically specify the included page in your *index.jsp*:

```
<jsp:include page="${somePage}"></jsp:include>
```

Here `somePage` should resolve to a valid path , should be an attribute of request or page or session or context . If you need more flexibility , then go for JSTL like `<c:import>` , which  provides more flexibility to the page author by allowing content to be specified from other web applications (or contexts) or even other web servers.

> 2.i would like to replace the include page in index.jsp to another jsp from themes.jsp

You can set a flag in *index.jsp* and do a conditional include using JSTL :

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${someExpressionHere}">
    <jsp:include page="Includes.jsp"></jsp:include>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${someOtherExpression}">
    <jsp:forward page="themes.jsp"/>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Inside the *themes.jsp* , you can include the required file :

```
<jsp:include page="someOther.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Comment: hi there. i guess there is already that line of code in my index.jsp. is there really no way to modify the include page from another jsp??

Comment: hi there. i am quite new to jstl but according to your codes. how would u change the flag condition in themes.jsp??